# How Spark distribute tasks to multiple workers

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When we write

```
RDD.map(x => x + 1)
```

This corresponds to a task that the `master` will send to all the workers to execute inside their partition.

But I'm interested in the detail of these magics. Let's say we submit a jar that contains all these functions using `spark-submit`. Once this jar submitted to the `master`, how the master do to understand and extract all these transformations and send it to all the workers ? Does it use the `reflecton` mechanism of java ?

For the sake of example, can you make a simple `map` and use for example `akka` under the hood to do the same magics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembled uber-JAR is not submitted to the master per-se, but rather to the `spark-submit` script. This script makes sure that the JAR is available to master and all worker nodes, and that all the classpaths are set correctly. Only then does it launch the application and starts the master node. Reflection is of no use here, because all the needed classes (including the compiled anonymous inner class that implements the closure in `.map(x => x + 1)`) are available in the JAR itself. When it's time to apply the closure in `map`, the master can use ordinary serialization to send the values on which the closure depends to the workers. The workers will then load the code of the closure from the JAR, supplement it with the necessary parameters from the deserialized closure, and then apply the closure to the RDDs.

You can of course implement rdd's with a `map` using Akka (that's what Spark does), but that's not exactly *simple*, at least not simple enough to fit into a single SO answer.

The interactive Spark repl is again a completely different story from the `spark-submit` script, because it has to compile new code while the application is running.

Comment: Can you point me to any resource to understand further this mechanism and probably with code example ?

Comment: @nam The point is that there is nothing special about this mechanism. If you have two instances of a program `Game`, and both instances have a JAR on classpath with class `SpaceShipPosition`, then you can simply serialize a `SpaceShipPosition`, send it over the network, deserialize it on the other side, and draw an enemy space ship at `SpaceShipPosition`. Here it is exactly the same: both master and worker have access to the same JAR. This JAR has a class named e.g. `MySparkApp$main$anonymFunc42` that implements `x => x + 1`. Master can serialize and send it. Worker can deserialize and run it.

Comment: Yes, but how does it detect the closure ? I mean if the function depends on the variable outside of the current scope like `x => x + globalVar`, then how does the `globalVar` is serialized too ?

Comment: @nam What do you mean "detect"? The closure is just an instance of a synthetic anonymous class. It has a weird artificial name, but otherwise, it's just yet another class. It can be serialized and sent over the network just like any other plain old java object. With some luck, this closure-object will have a non-`transient` field `globalVar`. With less luck, it will reference bunch of stuff it doesn't need, and then try to serialize everything but the kitchen sink. Then you get the Task Not Serializable errors in Spark. Search for "scala closure serialization" to get an overview.